# How can I add an icon to a toolbar item in VisualStudio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using VisualStudio 2012. There is the toolbar with a lot of icons. I can adapt the toolbar nearly fully to my wishes. 
But, there are certain commands that have not got an icon associated.

When I add one of these to the toolbar, there is not shown an icon, but the associated text. Which may be quite long. In my case, I want to have "Rebuild Solution" on the toolbar. This does not have an icon. And I'm using the german version of VS, where the text is "Projektmappe neu erstellen". Very long and quite unpleasing to see this much amount of space on the toolbar used by one command.

I'd like to have an icon here instead of this looong text. 
If it is impossible to show an icon, I'd be content with a possibility to rename the thing in the toolbar, e.g. to "X", which would use much less space on the toolbar, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set "X" name for a toolbar item in VS toolbar options with the **Modify Selection** button:

[image]